# Javascript While or If statement to run a set interval function with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a javascript while look that looks for the condition ":visible" on a DOM object and only runs the code when the DOM object is actually visible.

This is my code so far.

```
if (("#rightPanel").is(":visible") == true){
  // It's visible, run fetch on interval!
  setInterval(function() {
    updateChatField()
  }, 500);
} else {
    // Do Nothing!
};
```

What do I need to adjust to get my desired effect? Right  now I'm getting `("#rightPanel").is` is not a function.

Comment: `$` seems to be missing. It should be `$('#rightPanel')`

Comment: pretty sure you need a dollar sign before `("#rightPanel")`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `$` sign:

```
if ($("#rightPanel").is(":visible") == true){
  // It's visible, run fetch on interval!
  setInterval(function() {
    updateChatField()
  }, 500);
} else {
    // Do Nothing!
};
```

Comment: And you still get "`("#rightPanel").is` is not a function"?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I understood correctly, you need the interval to be constantly running so it detects when the element changes to visible. I'd suggest something like:

```
var $rightPanel; // cache the element

function checker() {
    if ($rightPanel.is(":visible"))
         updateChatField();
}

function init() {
    $rightPanel = $("rightPanel"); // cache
    window.setInterval(checker, 500);
}
```

Then to start it, just call `init()` after the page has loaded.